# Changing the text size of text in strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string

I was wondering if there was a way to alter the size of parts of a String in `strings.xml`. In my Java code I call

```
builder.setMessage(R.string.my_string)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to set the text size, similarly to how you can set the text to **bold** by doing this:

```
<string name="my_string"><b>My String</b></string>
```

Comment: i think dimension.xml will help

Comment: @Stacks28 I understand that, but I cannot find the syntax anywhere to set the dimensions of the String in strings.xml.

Comment: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring. you can use Spannable string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Html.fromHtml("your html string"), to do any style you want in HTML and then show it in the textview as shown below:

```
Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.yourStringResource));
yourTextView.setText(htmlText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

And the XML string.xml, must have the string declared as shown below:

```
<string name="yourStringResource"><![CDATA[BLA BLA BLA BLA <br/> BLABA <font color="blue">COLORED HTML</font>]]></string>
```

Regards!

Comment: Could you clarify what the stuff in the string resource means? I am unfamiliar with HTML text in Android. Are you aware of anywhere I can look or find information? Thanks.

Comment: CDATA stands for Character Data and it means that the data in these tags includes data that could be interpreted as XML markup, but should be ignored and be used as plain text, giving you the chance to set pure html within string resources. Anything else within these tags is regular html, if you want to learn more about it, go to http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp, its a really good place to start with HTML